# Using Mouse Buttons With Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, mouse, logitech

So, I recently switched to Ubuntu from Windows 10. One of the things I really liked was the ability to use my Logitech G602 Mouse's extra buttons to configure actions within programs. Specifically, I want to use it to push to talk in discord. How can I access the extra buttons (G6,7,8,9) inside Ubuntu? I already got G4 and G5 to work, as those are the standard forward/back buttons. How can I map the other ones?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mouse with 3 buttons and I've configured them based on this thread.

You will have to install xev to determine the mouse buttons and clicks.

```
sudo apt-get install xev
xev
```

run it in a terminal

it should prompt you a box figure point your mouse there and click your mouse from left click to right click as well as the buttons do this one at a time and take note of the button number(e.g left click = button = 1 )

then you can proceed to mapping by editing your xorg.conf(But make sure to have a backup first.

```
cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add this to the end of the line

```
Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "Configured Mouse"
        Driver          "mouse"
        Option          "CorePointer"
        Option          "Device"                "/dev/input/mice"
        Option          "Protocol"              "ExplorerPS/2"
        Option          "ZAxisMapping"          "6 7"
        Option          "Emulate3Buttons"       "true"
EndSection
```

Logout then login back again.

This is only an example of what I had where 8 and 9 are my buttons for forward and back mappings.

for more information I suggest you visit this link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

If it works, in discord settings in key bindings look for push to talk and assign the button you want.

Hope this helps.